# RoutedEventHandler vs RoutedEventArgs

Tags: wpf

What is the difference when we Register a custom Routed Event with GetType(RoutedEventHandler)
or GetType(RoutedEventArgs) ??

ex1 :

```
 Public Shared ReadOnly TextChangedEvent As RoutedEvent =   EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("TextChanged", _
               RoutingStrategy.Bubble, GetType(RoutedEventArgs), GetType(MyCustomTextBlock))
```

ex2 :

```
 Public Shared ReadOnly TextChangedEvent As RoutedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("TextChanged", _
               RoutingStrategy.Bubble, GetType(RoutedEventHandler), GetType(MyCustomTextBlock))
```

Comment: Someone learning WPF might wish to know why this question was voted down without so much as a comment. What is the OP's error. Those in the dark would remain in the dark.

Comment: I know that must be a delegate type but what made me to ask is because I have a book (Microsoft Windows Applications Development .Net Framework 4)and the example there it uses RoutedEventArgs and it works fine....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register your RoutedEvent you have to provide a number of arguments, including a delegate type.

**From MSDN**

```
public static RoutedEvent RegisterRoutedEvent(
       string name,
       RoutingStrategy routingStrategy,
       Type handlerType, // see note below.
       Type ownerType )
```

---

**handlerType**

Type: System.Type

*The type of the event handler. This must be a delegate type and cannot be null.*

---

**Selecting the type**

Therefore, your first example (ex1) is using an incorrect type. You don't pass an EventArgs. Instead you pass a delegate type.  There a many delegate types in .NET but you should be using one the derives from RoutedEvent args in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes I thought RoutedEventHandler is the correct answer... But because I have a book (Microsoft Windows Applications Development .Net Framework 4)and the example there it uses RoutedEventArgs and it works fine....